# Changing row colour if value set?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use the following script to change the row colour if a value in column N is set:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rows = sheet.getRange('n3:n700');
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    for (var x in values[i]){
      if (values[i][x] == '4'){
        var n = i + 1;
        sheet.getRange('a'+n+':n'+n).setBackgroundColor('red');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But unfortunately I get the following error message:

> Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

I've also tried switching to the new spreadsheets and using conditional formatting with a formula `if(n3 = "")` with no joy, and to be honest even if that worked I'm not sure if there is an easy way to apply conditional formatting to each line.

Comment: Where did you find the script? Any reference to that?

Comment: Sorry, I fount it here - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/t6xPcOkjNbQ/i2pGawavV34J

Comment: The _setBackgroundColor()_ is deprecated. Use _setBackground()_ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In new Google Sheets if you select A3:Z20 and Format, Conditional formatting... and enter:

```
=$N3<>""
```

for Custom formula is with a colour of your choice and Range: A3:Z20 then in the range A3:Z20 every cell should be coloured if the cell in Column N for the corresponding row is not empty.

Since such formatting is *conditional* the `IF` is not normally required.

Comment: :) Thank you. It was very useful to know how to apply it to my entire document too!

Comment: @pnuts Do you how to get this working when the matched criteria is in a dropdown field _(of a validation dialog)_? I guess `<>` stands for 'contains', I'd need an exact match, like when I have `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC` in the dropdown and I only want to match `BBB`.

Comment: Okay, found it (example with dialog value in column D): `=$D:$D="BBB"`.